# d3.zoomIdentity.translate().scale() doesn't respect d3.zoom().translateExtent()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to zoom to a bounding box when clicked in a map. I also want to limit the translate area within the container. When I try to center the feature with it's bounding box, the zoom does not account the `tranlateExtent` that was set to the `d3.zoom()` using the `d3.zoomTransform.translate([n,n]).scale(n)`. Here is the [block](https://bl.ocks.org/abdul-alim/30ecd2a1e140ca5f7bbae227cfc8552e/dec036818fd6eec8db43c8a5c202db09bad6bc2c) I made.

This is how I initiated the zoom.

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .translateExtent([[0, 0],[width, height]])
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
```

And I handle the click like this

```
function clicked(d) {

  var bounds = path.bounds(d),
        width = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
        height = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
        centerX = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
        centerY = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2;

    var scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(this._maxZoom, 1 / Math.max(width / zoomArea.width, height / zoomArea.height))),
        translate = [zoomArea.width / 2 - scale * centerX, zoomArea.height / 2 - scale * centerY];

  var zoomTo = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale);

  svg.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(zoom.transform, zoomTo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it enforcing the translateExtent manually.

```
var scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(this._maxZoom, 1 / Math.max(width / zoomArea.width, height / zoomArea.height))),

translate = [
    Math.min(zoomArea.x, Math.max(zoomArea.width / 2 - scale * x, zoomArea.width - zoomArea.width * scale)),
    Math.min(zoomArea.y, Math.max(zoomArea.height / 2 - scale * y, zoomArea.height - zoomArea.height * scale))
];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform

> This method requires that you specify the new zoom transform
>   completely, and **does not enforce the defined scale extent and
>   translate extent**, if any

Comment: I used this method because  `zoom.tranlateTo` & `zoom.scaleTo` does not work  at the same time with transition.